# Cannot click 'esc' key after exception logging

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a problem and i hope u guys can help me on this.

I have an app that is having problem in production. After trying to execute a function it will cause an error which is expected. Supposedly, it will go to catch area and trigger an error pop up. After i close the error pop up, somehow i cannot press 'esc' key to exit the form.

I have try this in my machine, i can press 'esc' key and exit the form successfully.

Is there a reason why this is happening? Please help.

```
    private void CalculateWeight()
    {
        try
        {
            double val = CommonBLL.CalculateWeight();
            txtWeight.Text = val.ToString("#,##0.00");
        }
        catch (CalculateWeightSystemException ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogging(ex, _screenName, _className, "CalculateWeight", null);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void ExceptionLogging(CalculateWeightSystemException floorException, string screenName, string UiClassName, string uiControl, params object[] parameters)
    {
          if (uiControl == "CalculateWeight")
                    GlobalMessageBox.Show("(" + result + ") - " + Constants.WEIGHT_ERROR, Constants.AlertType.Error, Messages.Warning, GlobalMessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
```

Code when esc is in base class of the form above.

```
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {

            if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Fyi, before the pop up error displayed, esc key is working fine. Only after the error displayed, and i click ok to close the error then the esc key is not working.

Comment: Please post [mcve], there is no way for us to know what is happening if we have no code.

Comment: Where is the code to handle the escape key being pressed?

Comment: I think that when pop up is showed your form lose the focus, so the key pressed event is intercepted by another Windows UI component.

Comment: An important detail for any dialog, a MessageBox as well, is that it must always have an owner window.  Winforms makes it too easy to not specify one explicitly, it then goes looking for *any* top-level window that is owned by the same thread to make it the parent.  If it finds the wrong one, or none at all, then you'll have this problem.  After you close the dialog the wrong window will have the focus and your ProcessCmdKey() method won't run.

Comment: Assuming `GlobalMessageBox` works like `MessageBox` just write `GlobalMessageBox.Show(this, "(" + result + ") - " + Constants.WEIGHT_ERROR, Constants.AlertType.Error, Messages.Warning, GlobalMessageBoxButtons.OK);`